# How to scan array by time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array and every object of the array is with 2 objects:
double = time in miliseconds
nsstring = string to print

and i want that my app will scan the array and when it will come to the time of the miliseconds it will print the nsstring.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "When it will come to the time of the milliseconds". Do you mean if the current time has the same number of milliseconds? This may be a bit too precise if the time is exact. Can it be within some time interval?

Comment: yes it not need to be exactly in the same miliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I assume the objects are called `MyObject`, and the array is called `objectArray`, so try this:

```
- (void)checkArrayForTimes; {
  float epsilon = 0.1;
  NSDate * currentTime = [NSDate date];
  float milliseconds = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
  milliseconds -= (int)milliseconds; // This mods out all of the seconds so you are only working with milliseconds.
  for(MyObject * myObject in objectArray){
    if(fabs(myObject.time - milliseconds) < epsilon){
      NSLog(@"%@", myObject.string);
    }
  }
}
```

In your .h file, add the line:

```
NSDate * startDate;
```

Then, in your `viewDidLoad:` method, add the lines:

```
    // Note, you can change the 0.05 to fit your needs.
    startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(checkArrayForTimes) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

(***Note:***, you may need to use a `NSDateFormatter` to get an `NSDate` with `0` milliseconds.) Finally, in your `dealloc` method, add:

```
[startDate release];
```

Hope that Helps!